# Do passphrases need to be run through PBKDF2? Almost impossible to brute force?

Tags: encryption

Passphrases normally contain more data then passwords and can provide more entropy. It seems like it would still be hard to brute force a passphrase w/o using PBKDF2, assuming a user didn't select a famous quote, movie line, etc... I define a passphrase in this example as at least 22 characters.

For example, if a user used a DiceWare generated passphrase of 6 words from a 10,000 word dictionary, we would get 10,000^6 number of possible phrases.

If a super computer could do 33.6 X 10^15 operations per second and it took 2,000 operations(w/o PBKDF2) to try 1 guess it would take (10,000^6)/((33.6 X 10^15)/2,000) or about 1887 years to brute force in the worst case.

Does this and the above example make sense? Thank you very much!

Comment: How would you enforce the usage of a strong passphrase in general? The whole raison d'etre of *password-based* KDF's is to compensate for poorly chosen passwords. If you take that out of the equation, by ensuring your passphrase has as much entropy as a typical key, then you vacuously don't need a PBKDF, only a plain KDF...

Comment: 6 words randomly chosen from 10000 word dictionary are still below 80 bit strength, i.e. less than minimum key strength recommended for cryptographic uses nowadays. Furthermore, it may be very hard to ensure in practice that all users use keys this strong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Passphrases **normally** contain more data then passwords and **can** provide more entropy. It seems like it would still be hard to brute force a passphrase w/o using PBKDF2, **assuming** a user didn't select a famous quote, movie line, etc... I **define** a passphrase in this example as at least 22 characters.

What you're saying here is that there are passphrases which have large entropy. This doesn't prove anything. There are shorter passwords with large entropy. Length doesn't correlate so much with entropy when it's a human doing the choosing.

(Note: I'll use *password* and *passphrase* interchangeably from now on, because there is no difference between the two, technically speaking. A *passphrase* is a password that happens to consist of several words in a human language concatenated together.)

Entropy of a password made of 8 printable ASCII characters: 52 bits
Entropy of a password made of 4 Diceware words: 51 bits
(For uniformly random selections. The Diceware list consists of exactly 7776 words.)

The more randomness goes into a password, the harder it is for a human to memorize. If you use a slow hashing function rather than a fast one, you reduce the entropy that a password needs to have to escape cracking. It's a trade-off between spending more CPU time and requiring humans to memorize more.

Given that even decent passwords strain the capabilities of humans to memorize (and keep in mind that most people have tens if not hundreds of passwords), the choice is clear: you must provide them as slow a password hashing function as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Having a very strong password independent of needing a kdf has benefits like you have pointed out.

However even a strong password is dependent on a hash in order to be secured from password table dumps, otherwise it doesn't need to be guessed.

This logic should only be used to make the decision to use strong passwords however, and not to be lazy if you are implementing security. Most people don't use strong ones.

Answer (score 1):

If your password needs to be run through a PBKDF depends on the use case. PBKDF's such as PBKDF2 have multiple benefits and properties:

- they can hide a password in a database, for when the database gets stolen

  - they provide a salt to hide identical passwords and protect against rainbow tables
  - they use the iteration count to make brute force attacks harder (but only by a linear amount)
- they can extract the entropy from a given value, i.e. return a fixed size output
- they can expand the amount of secret material to a larger value (mainly useful when the output is used as cryptographic input such as key or IV)

Now say you have a *secure system* where you use the pass phrase for authentication. For this authentication there is a limited number of tries or the passwords have a high amount of entropy. In that case a PBKDF does not make much sense.

If your passwords already have a verifiable amount of entropy in them, then a KBKDF - such as HKDF - makes more sense than a PBKDF2 - you don't need the iteration count. But as others have pointed out, in general you cannot easily estimate or ensure the amount of entropy of a pass phrase.

If you just use a hash as poor mans KDF, then you don't have a salt. This means that the output will be identical for the same pass phrase; duplicate pass phrases may become a problem.

If you want to have a fixed sized table entry in your database, then it may make sense to at least use a KDF, otherwise you will have to use an upper bound for the size of the pass phrase.

In the end then it becomes the question why *not* to use a PBKDF *such as* PBKDF2.

---

Note that PBKDF2 is not considered a great option by many to perform expansion as it gives advantage to an attacker.

Comment: As you can see, I'm struggling a bit because the use case and the security of the password storage was not specified in the question. Usually a PBKDF2 is beneficial, but there *are* use cases where it is not required. A PIN is usually not run through a PBKDF2 either.